# Jetpack Compose onClick ripple is not propagating with a circular motion?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

As can be seen in gif

[image]

when `Column` that contains of Text, Spacer, and `LazyRowForIndexed` is touched ripple is not propagating with circular motion. And it gets touched effect even when horizontal list is touched.

```
@Composable
fun Chip(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, text: String) {
    Card(
        modifier = modifier,
        border = BorderStroke(color = Color.Black, width = Dp.Hairline),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, top = 4.dp, end = 8.dp, bottom = 4.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(16.dp, 16.dp)
                    .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.preferredWidth(4.dp))
            Text(text = text)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TutorialSectionCard(model: TutorialSectionModel) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 8.dp)
            .clickable(onClick = { /* Ignoring onClick */ })
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Text(text = model.title, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
        Spacer(Modifier.preferredHeight(8.dp))
        Providers(AmbientContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text(model.description, style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
        Spacer(Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))
        LazyRowForIndexed(items = model.tags) { _: Int, item: String ->
            Chip(text = item)
            Spacer(Modifier.preferredWidth(4.dp))
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TutorialSectionCardPreview() {

    val model = TutorialSectionModel(
        clazz = MainActivity::class.java,
        title = "1-1 Column/Row Basics",
        description = "Create Rows and Columns that adds elements in vertical order",
        tags = listOf("Jetpack", "Compose", "Rows", "Columns", "Layouts", "Text", "Modifier")

    )

    Column {
        TutorialSectionCard(model)
        TutorialSectionCard(model)
        TutorialSectionCard(model)
    }
}
```

What should be done to have circular effect, but not when list itself or an item from list is touched, or scrolled?

Comment: I just want your effect without ripples, I don’t know how to achieve it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to apply a Theme to your composable, which in turn provides a default ripple factory, or you have to set the ripple explicitly:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TutorialSectionCardPreview() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        Column {
            TutorialSectionCard
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 8.dp)
            .clickable(
                onClick = { /* Ignoring onClick */ },
                indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true)
            )
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
      // content
    }
```

(As of compose version 1.0.0-alpha09 there seems to be no way to prevent the ripple from showing when content is scrolled)

Comment: It works. Would you mind giving more details about why it does not work with `onClick` only and works with `indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true)`?

Comment: And i guess it should be `rememberRippleIndication` not `rememberRipple `

Comment: It is rememberRipple since 1.0.0-alpha09.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this approach:

```
        .clickable(
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
            indication = rememberRipple(
                color = Color.Black
            ),
            onClick = {

            }
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently rememberRipple() has been deprecated and we have to use new provided APIs.

rememberRipple() -> ripple()

```
Modifier.clickable(
    onClick = {},
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = ripple()
)
```

More info in the official docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/user-interactions/migrate-indication-ripple#migrate-remember-ripple

Edit: Please someone correct me if I am wrong, but at the time of this writing, this is only available in `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-alpha01` BUT has not yet been released... So we have a deprecated method that throws error when you compile, and the solution has not been released yet.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue after going up to the latest version of materil 3. I could not find a soltuion and your comment saved me. since it works well now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also figured out how to keep ripple only for the card not the scrollable list that contains tags. To prevent ripple only move through cards use a `Box` which places it's children as a stack, and add clickable to section that contains header and text.

[image: ripple]

```
@Composable
fun TutorialSectionCard(
    model: TutorialSectionModel,
    onClick: ((TutorialSectionModel) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 3.dp, horizontal = 8.dp),
        elevation = 1.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
        ) {
            TutorialContentComponent(onClick, model)
            TutorialTagsComponent(model)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TutorialContentComponent(
    onClick: ((TutorialSectionModel) -> Unit)?,
    model: TutorialSectionModel
) {
    Column(Modifier
        .clickable(
            onClick = { onClick?.invoke(model) }
        )
        .padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        Text(
            text = model.title,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )

        // Vertical spacing
        Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))

        // Description text
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text(model.description, style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
        // Vertical spacing
        Spacer(Modifier.height(36.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TutorialTagsComponent(model: TutorialSectionModel) {
    Column(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {

        // Horizontal list for tags
        LazyRow(content = {

            items(model.tags) { tag ->
                TutorialChip(text = tag)
                Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

same as @jns just added an extra line

```
modifier = modifier
    .clickable (
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }, // without this indication parameter gets an error
        indication = rememberRipple(
            bounded = true
        ),
        onClick = { 
           //on click
        }
    )
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33999330)

Answer (score 0):

To apply the circular effect globally you can provide the unbounded ripple indication to all components in the tree:

```
val ripple = rememberRipple(bounded = false) // Applies circular ripple animation effect
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalIndication provides ripple
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = ...,
        typography = ...,
        shapes = ...,
        content = content
    )
}
```